# How to view all of the directories/files in a Git-Stash?

Tags: git

Trying to figure out how the stash works. I have the following "git status"

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   ../../../root/index.tt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    Coupons.pm
    ../../../root/coupons/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

When I do a "git stash save -a", then issue the command "git stash show -p" will only show me the following, I don't see the directory above or the file "Coupons.pm", but if I apply the stash, it will then be back.

```
index 629342697e..ecd82eb69f 100644
--- a/View/Web/OmniHUB2/root/index.tt
+++ b/View/Web/SomeSite/root/index.tt
@@ -120,6 +120,9 @@
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="/someinterface">SOME Interface</a>
       </div>
       [% END %]
+      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
+         <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="/coupons">Coupons</a>
+      </div>
    </div>
 </div>

lines 1-14/14 (END)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

How `git stash` works is pretty simple, really.  It's the *consequences* that get complicated.  In this case, your untracked file is in an extra commit, which `git stash show` doesn't bother showing.

To show what's in this extra commit, you can use:

```
git show stash^3
```

which will show each such file as added.

#### Long

What `git stash` does is to make two commits—or sometimes three, and you're using this third commit mode—neither of which is on any branch.  The required two commits save the contents of the *index*, and the contents of the *work-tree*.  The third commit, if it exists, saves the untracked-except-ignored or untracked-and-ignored files (and no other files).

Hence, what is *in* the commit is two (or three) snapshots, along with the rest of the metadata that accompanies every commit, i.e., two (or three) metadata blocks as well.  With one exception, the metadata in these blocks is not particularly useful and can mostly be ignored.

It's also worth mentioning here how `git status` works, as these are related.  You need to be aware of the fact that Git provides the thing called, variously, the *index*, the *staging area*, or (rarely these days) the *cache*, depending on which part of Git is doing the calling.  Since this is mostly about `git stash`, all I'll say here is that `git status` runs *two* comparisons: it diffs `HEAD` vs the index to find what it calls *files staged for commit*, then, separately, diffs the index vs the work-tree to find what it calls *files not staged for commit*.

#### Background

You probably already know that each Git commit holds a complete snapshot of all of your source files (well, all of the files that were tracked at the time you made the commit).  You probably also know that a commit carries *metadata:* who made it (user name and email address), when (date-and-time stamp), and why (log message), plus the hash ID of the commit's *parent:* the commit that comes just before this one.  Each commit gets its own unique hash ID, different from that of every other commit, but computed in such a way that every Git in the universe will agree that *that* commit gets *that* hash ID.

Because each commit remembers the hash ID of its immediate predecessor, we only need to know the hash ID of the *last* commit in any commit chain:

```
A <-B <-C   (need C's hash ID)
```

We have Git read commit `C` to find `B`'s hash ID, then read `B` to find `A`'s hash ID.  A branch name like `master` simply holds the hash ID of the *last* commit in the series.

To make a *new* commit, Git simply saves whatever is in the index *right now*, adds your name and email and so on, sets the *parent* to the *current* commit, and writes all that out as a new commit, which generates the new commit's new and unique hash ID.  We'll call that new commit `D`, and `D` points back to `C`, so we'll draw this as:

```
A--B--C   <-- branch
       \
        D
```

To remember that `D` has been added to branch `branch`, Git now stuffs `D`'s new hash ID into the *name* `branch`, giving us:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- branch
```

For various reasons, including saving a lot of space, the files inside commits are in a special, read-only, Git-only, frozen, compressed form.  Only Git can use this and no one, not even Git, can *change* any of them.  I like to call these files *freeze-dried*, though this is not an official Git term.

You, of course, need your files unfrozen and rehydrated.  Those files go into your work-tree, where you can see them and work on them.  So there are, necessarily, *two* copies of every file: the freeze-dried one in the current commit, plus the usable version in your work-tree.

Git adds the index / staging-area as an in-between landing or launching point, though: there's a freeze-dried copy of the file in the index, too.  Unlike the committed version, though, you can *replace* this one any time.  That's what `git add` does: it freeze-dries the work-tree copy, and writes that into the index, replacing the previous index copy—or creating the file *in* the index, if it wasn't there before.

The fact that Git saves what's in the *index*, not what's in the *work-tree*, is why we have to run `git add` so often.  It also makes `git commit` extremely fast: there's no need to scan the entire work-tree, re-compressing every file to see if it has changed.  You already re-compressed any important files when you `git add`ded them.  The freeze-dried index copy is already in the right format to go into a new commit.  Git can just package them up and it's done.

#### Tracked vs untracked files

The definition of a *tracked file* is very simple: it's any file name that is in the index *right now*.  Since `git commit` saves what's in the index, the tracked version of the file is what will be in the new commit.  It doesn't matter what's in the work-tree right now: the file just has to be in the index.  Whatever form it has there, *that* is what will be committed.

An untracked file is therefore also very simply defined: it's any file whose name is in the work-tree but not in the index.  (If it's neither in the index *nor* in the work-tree, it just doesn't exist.  How many files that don't exist are there that aren't in your index or work-tree right now? :-) That actually has a countable answer on most systems, but it's such a huge number it's not worth thinking about too much: it's on the order of 254<sup>255</sup> on Linux, for instance.)  An untracked file can be simply untracked, in which case Git will complain about it sometimes, or untracked and also *ignored*, which shuts up the complaints.

(There's no such thing as a tracked-but-ignored file: if a file is tracked, it's just not ignored by definition.  There *are* some special status bits you can set on files in the index, but let's not get into that here.)

#### `git stash`'s commits

Near the middle of [the `git stash` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), they mention the `I` and `W` commits, which I usually call the `i` and `w` commits.  The job of the stash command is to make these commits without changing the current branch in any way, then to update `refs/stash`, rather than a branch name, to save one of their hash IDs.  This needs to be enough to find both commits.

The stash code makes the `i` commit in almost the usual way.  As we saw above, `git commit` makes a commit by wrapping up the freeze-dried files, setting up the metadata with the parent being the current commit, writing out the commit, and writing the new commit's hash ID into the current branch name.  If we just stop `git commit` from doing the *last* step, and save the hash ID somewhere else, we get just what we need:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- branch
          \
           i   (git-stash will save i's hash ID somewhere)
```

Now `git stash` needs to save the current *work-tree* somehow, and if you've asked for it, save a third commit as well.  Let's assume for now that we don't need the third commit, and just make the `w` one.  What we'd like is to set things up so that `w` holds copies of all the work-tree files that are *tracked*.  To do this, the stash code makes a second, temporary index, and copies into it all the work-tree versions of all the files.  It uses some tricky code to avoid re-freeze-drying unnecessarily, but in principle it's just:

```
for (every file $f in the real index): copy $f into temporary index
```

The stash code then makes the `w` commit from this temporary index, using both `i` *and* the current commit as its (two) parents:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- branch
         |\
         i-w   (git-stash now has w's commit hash too)
```

Then, `git stash` just adds `w` to `refs/stash`, using a push-style operation if `refs/stash` already exists, or creating `refs/stash` if not:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- branch
         |\
         i-w   <-- refs/stash
```

We'll get to the final bits of `git stash` in a moment.

#### The third commit in a three-commit stash

If you choose to make a *third* commit, which I call `u` for "untracked" files, the stash code writes this third commit out *before* writing out the `w` commit.  To make the commit, `git stash` lists out all the untracked files, either including (`-a` / `--all`) or excluding (`-u` / `--include-untracked`) the ignored subset of the untracked files.  It then does a trick similar to that for the `w` commit: it makes a temporary index and copies each of the listed files into that temporary index, from which it makes the `u` commit.

The `stash` code gives the `u` commit *no* parent.  This `u` commit just dangles out there unattached to anything:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- branch
         |
         i

         u
```

Then, with both `i` and `u` commits in place, `git stash` goes back to making the `w` commit, using a temporary index as before and copying the work-tree files into it based on their presence in the real/regular index.  Then, when it makes the `w` commit, it gives `w` a *third* parent, namely the `u` commit it just made:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- branch
         |\
         i-w   <-- refs/stash
          /
         u
```

and writes the `w` commit's hash ID into `refs/stash` as before.

#### The last step of creating a stash is to clean the index and work-tree

Having made these two or three commits, `git stash` now has to clean up the index and work-tree.  The default here is simply to run `git reset --hard`, which copies all the freeze-dried files from the current commit to the index and then on to the work-tree.  When using `-u` or `-a` to make a third commit, `git stash` also uses `git clean` or equivalent to remove any of the files it put in that third commit.

(With the `--keep-index` option, `git stash` resets the work-tree to match the index, which it leaves alone so that the index matches the `i` commit.  Any cleaning from `-a` or `-u` remains the same.)

#### The consequences of a three-commit stash

In order to restore (`pop` or `apply`) a stash properly, Git needs the files in the index and/or work-tree to be "clean".  For two-commit stashes, Git doesn't make this a hard requirement: it just tries to merge the stash into the current work-tree.  The effect can be a big mess and in some cases it's difficult or impossible to reverse it.  This means it's often unwise to `git stash apply` or `git stash pop` if `git status` says anything other than *nothing to commit, working tree clean;* but this is your choice.

For three-commit stashes, though, Git is more careful.  Oddly, this can be *more* frustrating.  In particular, Git tries not to clobber any work-tree files that exist and are untracked and will be overwritten by checking out the files from the `u` commit.  Essentially, this means that you often must run `git clean` just to check out a stash made with `-a` or `-u`.

When you do successfully extract such a stash, Git will have:

- Extracted the `u` commit files to the work-tree (these should all be new now, and untracked, and depending on the state of your `.gitignore` files now as compared to then, probably similarly ignored/not-ignored as before).
- Merged the `w` commit files with your existing work-tree.
- If you used `--index`, applied the result of diffing `i` against its parent to your existing index using `git apply --cached`.

Two of these steps are the same as for any stash.

If the stash is attached to commit `D`, and the index and work-tree are pristine and match `D`, `git stash apply --index` will always succeed (barring any `git stash` bugs that is).  Hence:

```
git checkout $(git rev-parse refs/stash^1)
git reset --hard
git stash apply --index
```

will cleanly apply a two-commit stash and completely restore the state from `git stash`, but for a three-commit stash you must add a `git clean` command, using either `-df` or `-dfx` to remove the `u` files.  Note that both `git reset --hard` and `git clean -dfx` can be destructive of work that's not saved anywhere in Git, so it's a good idea to make sure such work is saved somewhere (perhaps, oddly enough, using `git stash save -a` :-) ).

Answer (score 3):

You can view all existing stashes with `git stash list`. You'll get something like this:

```
stash@{0}: WIP on branch-1: 1af3a3456 Add config file
stash@{1}: WIP on branch-1: f8325f42d Update some function
stash@{2}: WIP on branch-2: bae22df24 Merge branch 'branch-3' of
```

You can see the diff of a specific stash with `git stash show -p stash@{2}`.

You should definitely read the git-stash documentation at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash